# Sending email from asp.net application using Network Service account

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, smtp

I'm writing Email module for company internal system. Basically it will only notify users about changes in the project.

Currently I have all configuration except credentials for SMTP.
I want that email would be sent using ***Netwrok Service*** account not currently logged on user. Is it possible? I could not find any information regarding this anywhere.

Comment: I can always create a dedicated account on your SMTP server and use that credentials. You don't need the credentials of the logged on user.

Comment: IT guys says that they wont create account because it will be used only to send emails. I think it is because of licenses. 
So I need to use Network Service account

Comment: You can't do this because the Network Service account is not valid in your SMTP server. This account is a "kind" of computer credential. Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms684272(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: We have TFS on-premise and I configure SMTP setting there and there is option to use TFS account to send email that is Network Service. So I thought that it is possible.